# How to get transparent background of PictureBox, to get a proper image transparency?

Tags: c#, user-interface

[image]

I am actually making a splash screen and set my from property to

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
    this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
}
```

but the image is aperaing something like this

[image]

This is how it looks like in the form. 
I want the diamonds at the back of "Inventory management system" to be transparent as i have shown in 1st picture. Tell me how can i do it.

Comment: Maybe use PNG image with transparency?

Comment: It is already a PNG imge

Comment: You can see the opacity of the green color behind the heading is low in 1st image I want such effect in pictureBox

Comment: You mean Translucent, not Transparent.  Transparent means they have no color.  Translucent mean they "bleed through" the background.  This is typically set with Opacity settings.

Comment: @fahadkhalid You might be using a PNG image, but not every PNG image has transparency. You should try loading it up in an image editor and making sure it has an alpha channel and the transparency is correct. That will be a lot easier than trying to do it on your form.

Comment: I have checked the transparency is correct, I have checked it on photoshop